# $X_n$ ~ $\Gamma(n,n)$, find the limit in Law of $X_n$

Tags: probability, limits, characteristic-functions

I am investigating the following idea. 
Let $X_n$ ~ $\Gamma(n,n)$. I want to find the limit in Law of this random variable.

I tried using Paul Levy theorem that says the following: If I find the limit of the characteristic function equal to some function $\theta(t)$ continuous in 0, then there exists a random variable X such as $X_n \to X$ with $\theta$ as its characteristic function.

Following this idea I tried calculating the following limit:

$$ \lim \Big(\frac{1}{1-int}\Big)^n$$ 
However to me this goes to 0. But that is not possible because such a characteristic function cannot exist. Is this the right approach?

Comment: There is another parameterization of  $\Gamma$ distribution for which 
$$
\varphi_n=(1-it/n)^n\to e^{-it}.
$$

Comment: Indeed: scale $n$ or $1/n$?

Comment: @Did What do you mean by scale? Anyway, such a characteristic function is only for the X = 1 constant random variable, am I right?

Comment: "What do you mean by scale?" One of the parameters of every gamma distribution. Please se the WP page, if refreshing your memories is needed.

Comment: I see. I used the following: $ \Big( 1 - \frac{it}{n} \Big)^{-n}$, but I get $e^{it}$